# My Configuration file is unable to find the hibernate mapping

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, configuration, mapping

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VDcB.jpg)[This is my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5ft9.png)

Please check my configuration file and mapping file, the config file is unable to locate the mapping resource even though they are in the same folder.

**My hibernate Config file**

[>

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
> "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
> "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
>
> <hibernate-configuration>
> <session-factory>
>
> <!-- Related to the connection START -->
> <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
> </property>
> <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:3306:XE</property>
> <property name="connection.user">root</property>
> <property name="connection.password">maherukh</property>
> <!-- Related to the connection END -->
>
> <!-- Related to hibernate properties START -->
> <property name="show_sql">true </property>
> <property name="dialet">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect </property>
> <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update </property>
> <!-- Related to hibernate properties END -->
>
> <!-- Related to mapping START -->
> <mapping resource="Product.hbm.xml" />
> <!-- Related to the mapping END -->
>
> </session-factory>
> </hibernate-configuration>][2]
> ```

**My hibernate Mapping file**

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
> "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
> "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
>
> <hibernate-mapping>
> <class name="Product" table="PRODUCTS">
>
> <id name="productId" column="pid"  >
> <generator class="assigned" />
> </id>
>
> <property name="proName" column="pname" />
> <property name="price"/>
>
> </class>
> </hibernate-mapping>
> ```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: Product.hbm.xml not found
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:517)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1511)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1479)

Comment: ^^^^ this is the error its giving.

Comment: also please check the screenshot that I have addded.

Comment: both xml should be same location under WEB-INF folder.or give particular Product.hbm.xml location. for example <mapping resource="test/animals/orm.xml"/>

Comment: both xml's are in the same folder "str". This project I have created according to the given steps in : http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/hibernate-hello-world-program-in-eclipse/

Comment: copy your both hbm file from str folder and paste under src folder not str folder.

Comment: add all the required jars.and hibernate.cfg.xml and Product.hbm.xml under src folder.not str. because str is a package.@Mahe

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with : **<mapping resource="str/Product.hbm.xml" />**
By default your classpath is src so hibernate will probably search your mapping files in src

Comment: yes I did that ... then its giving this error -> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource str/Product.hbm.xml

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: /str/Product.hbm.xml not found

Comment: If you have a invalidMappingException hibernate found your document but failed to parse it,  so str/Product.hbm.xml is the good path, now you have a parsing error in the hbm fil could you provide it ?

Comment: Also provide your complete stacktrace for mappingException, the reason should be indicated on it.

Comment: thanx @all but still giving error. Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource product.hbm.xml,,,,,, Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: class Product not found while looking for property: productId,,,,Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Product

Comment: @abbas A - hbm file is already provided above "My hibernate Mapping file" please see and tell me what exactly is the error regarding parsing.

Comment: Ok now the issue is clear eclipse is unable to find your Product class, try to put your str folder in build path as follow : right click on str directory then build path > use as source folder. and run again you project